# Building a collection from the location of the document being processed, not of the transforming stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to load a collection of files in a subfolder ("alto") of the xml file being transformed.

This is very close:

```
<xsl:variable name="files" select="collection('./alto/?select=*.xml')"/>
```

This command gets the collection right, except it is directing at the folder that the stylesheet is in, not the document being transformed. I can get the full file path using "document-uri(.)", but I'm not sure how to chop off the file name at the end so I can append "./alto/?select=*.xml" to it. I feel like I am very close, something with tokenize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `select="collection(resolve-uri('./alto/?select=*.xml', base-uri()))"`.

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. I spent hours fighting with tokenizer and variables and your solution just WORKS.